# Bootloaders - Booting an MBR only OS using a UEFI only BIOS

Tags: bios, uefi, bootloader, mbr

A long time ago, in a computer lab far far away, I stumbled upon a bootloader which dared to cross the boundaries between MBR and EFI.

It's name was [Clover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/).

Using clover, you could boot any number of Operating systems that had previously been beyond your reach, simply because you didn't have that expensive new computer with a fancy UEFI BIOS.

Today, I am looking for the exact opposite. I have several MBR only OS's that I wish to install on UEFI only computers. Is there a way to do this that is as simple as Clover?

Comment: Just enable legacy mode.

Comment: Most EFIs provide a Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which enables them to launch BIOS programs. In the firmware setup, this is sometimes called "legacy boot support" or something similar. Whether this is practical for you depends on the details of your configuration, such as what OSes you want to install and whether they're all BIOS-mode OSes or if you want a mix of BIOS and EFI installations. If your computer lacks a CSM (as some do), the only option I'm aware of is to use virtualization in another OS.

Comment: @RodSmith My computer has no CSM, I do have another laptop with CSM, but that's not the point of this question.

Comment: "CSM" *is* the answer to your question. That's the tool for the job. If your computer truly lacks a CSM (such an omission is very rare on system with 64-bit EFIs), then you're out of luck, unless you resort to virtualization. It's my understanding that, for technical reasons, a CSM cannot be loaded on a CSM-less EFI. If you care to post more details about what you hope to achieve and why you want to do it this way, perhaps I or somebody else could offer more advice. Given the vague requirements you've posted, though, it's CSM, virtualization, or nothing.

Comment: @RodSmith I am not trying to complete any goal, I simply wanted to know if any Clover-like solution had been created to load MBR only bootloaders on UEFI only systems. The reason I ask here, is because of the immense knowledge and personal experience that Google didn't provide me with.

Comment: @RodSmith BTW, I'm a big fan of your work.

Comment: AFAIK, no such tool exists, outside of the CSM. A discussion on an EFI developers' mailing list suggested that it's not possible to write such a thing as a standalone solution. Of course, that raises the objection of Clarke's First Law: "When a distinguished but elderly scientist states that something is possible, he is almost certainly right. When he states that something is impossible, he is very probably wrong."

Comment: I fear that the only solution is going to be to boot an UEFI capable OS and add virtualisation.